# MCMC convergence with spBayes

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, spatial, hierarchical-bayesian

I am running spBayes to fit a model like

```
y ~ ID + 0
```

and I am using an exponential model for the spatial component.

I am a bit confused on the outcome of the MCMC simulation. In particular while the nugget, partial sill and the covariates' parameters seem to have converged (the trace plots show good mixing) this doesn't seem to be true for the range.

[image]

Is this the case? If yes, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: A Markov chain may well mix better on some components than others. And show more correlation on some components than others.

Comment: @Xi'an so would you say this Markov chain has converged?

Comment: I cannot state whether or not a Markov chain has converged when I know nothing about the target, as MCMC is a "what you get is what you see" method. All I can say is  that the chain shows a stable behaviour, with a stronger correlation on the $\phi$ component. To assess convergence more thoroughly, you would need several chains run from highly different starting points or with tempered versions of the target.